# Incorrect site redirection using Apache/RSA WebAgent

Tags: apache, redirect

We are using CentOS based Apache 2.4.20 along with RSA WebAgent version 7.1. We have two internal (for now) sites we are protecting with RSA WebAgent, and which have vhost entries that look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ourcompany.com
    ServerName server1.ourcompany.lan
    ServerAlias server1 
    ServerAlias server1.ourcompany.lan

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://10.40.50.60:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.40.50.60:8080/

        ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/log/httpd/app1-error.log /var/log/httpd/app1/error-%Y-%m-%d.log"
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/log/httpd/app1-access.log /var/log/httpd/app1/access-%Y-%m-%d.log" combined

    ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

and...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ourcompany.com
    ServerName app2.ourcompany.lan
    ServerAlias app2
    ServerAlias app2.ourcompany.lan

    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://10.40.50.61:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.40.50.61:8080/

        ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/log/httpd/app2-error.log /var/log/httpd/app2/error-%Y-%m-%d.log"
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog -S /var/log/httpd/app2-access.log /var/log/httpd/app2/access-%Y-%m-%d.log" combined

    ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

Both of these sites can be logged onto successfully via RSA WebAgent so we know they work. The problem we have is when the user logs onto one site (say app1.ourcompany.lan), and then subsequently attempts logon to the second site(app2.ourcompany.lan) using same browser instance (different tab). In this case once the RSA authentication has succeeded the user is not redirected to the correct site (app2) but is instead redirected to the first site (app1). This issue also occurs in the reverse order as well (once logged on to app2 the subsequent logon attempt for app1 will redirect user to app2).

At this point we are not sure if this is an RSA WA config issue or an Apache issue. Any help or insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we know the cause of the problems now, but not the why. The cause was identical cookie names being used for each of the two sites. The fix was to simply rename one of the cookies to something different. Restart apache and presto now it all works. Why this is happening is the mystery. From all we've read cookie names should be cross-usable on separate sites. It could be that each site is really just a different subdomain and not a different domain. Regardless the solution is fine for our needs.